# iOS data synchronization and importing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm in the process of writing an iOS application which involves messaging, since this is one of the only functions of the app, I am trying to optimize the import and syncing process as to have the least amount of impact on the user experience.

What I want to know is the following:

What is the best type of **architecture** or **pattern** (persistence agnostic) to keep my app in sync with our back-end?

What I currently have:

I have a singleton NSObject class, lets call it "Manager".

This class maintains:

- An NSThread which runs for the entirety of the app's life.
- Several NSDate properties which represent the last time a particular "full sync" or "profile sync" occurred.

I've been reading from several sources that there are better alternatives to NSThread (such as GCD), but haven't really seen any examples that fit my use case. I guess what I am really trying to ask is, would it be better (more performant) to just have a class with timers that keep the app in sync as opposed to the long running NSThread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the server time (timestamp) along with the response from the server.

On your client you save this time and send it along with each future request. Each request must also update this "update token".

This now makes it really simple for your server to determine what you already have and what not.

I'm pretty sure there are better and more complex ways that but when your server sends everything since the last query (even missed / outdated) you don't even need some sort of integrity check.

I think there is a huge variety of good and correct answers. It completely depends on the use case.

This, though, is a simple concept I used in one of my B2B apps as well.

Comment: We're already using a hash to determine if we're missing anything, I think the question that I wanted to ask deals more with the performance of using NSThread as opposed to using some other method to maintain synchronization. I do appreciate your input though. I just haven't really come across this problem before, so I'm really unsure if what I'm currently using is best practice.

Comment: The hash will only tell you _if_ something changed, not what. Also hashing is more effort than storing a double (timestamp). Specially when dealing with big data, this can be a huge performance issue. I think best would be periodically calling the API or implementing push notifications and updating then. Also keeping everything in it's default thread should just work fine.

Comment: Also why do you want an extra thread? Are you synchronizing endlessly or very often? I'll think about it again and refine my answer

Comment: We are synchronizing endlessly because the user can have multiple apps across devices, so we want to ensure that profile settings, messages, conversations are the same throughout.

Comment: I'd HIGHLY reccommend not doing so. I developed a huge database which was synchronized between multiple teams using apple push (actually ONE long polling request made by the system). This worked really well and doing "security checks" at a larger interval will catch the really unlikely push fails. They arrive usually in between 0.5 and 5 sec. And I rellay doubt your users would be annoyed by a small delay... Otherwise yes, put in in a separate thread.

Comment: Ok, I'll definitely look into utilizing push notifications to synchronize, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create the Dependency injector in your manager class. Suppose you are having 8 models, M1, M2, M3,  N1,N2, N3, K1, K2.

Where unless and until M1 model is not updated, you cannot update M2 and similarly with N1->N2 and K1->K2.

Now for each sequence, create separate custom dispatch_queue_t objects at Manager level.

e.g.

```
dispatch_async(CUSTOM_QUEUE_1, ^{
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url1"]
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            // update model updated time and start next dependent request
            [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url2"]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                // update model updated time and start next dependent request
                .....
            }] resume];

        }] resume];
});


dispatch_async(CUSTOM_QUEUE_2, ^{
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url3"]
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            // update model updated time and start next dependent request
            [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url4"]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                // update model updated time and start next dependent request
                .....
            }] resume];

        }] resume];
});
```